# Rejigging a floating point equation 

Tags: floating-point, precision, linear-algebra

I'd like to know if there is a way to improve the accuracy of calculating a slope.  (This came up a few months back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696573/unexpected-loss-of-precision-when-dividing-doubles/917290#917290)).

It seems by changing:

```
float get_slope(float dXa, float dXb, float dYa, float dYb) {
    return (dXa - dXb)/(dYa - dYb);
}
```

to

```
float get_slope(float dXa, float dXb, float dYa, float dYb) {
    return  dXa/(dYa - dYb) - dXb/(dYa - dYb);
}
```

might be an improvement.  Suggestions?

Edit: It's precision I'm after, not efficiency.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: C.  But I'm curious how that might qualify peoples responses.

Comment: Aside: Floating point numbers are truly weird. The closer you get to zero, the more precision you get. By that I mean floats can represent many more values in the range [0,0.1] than in the range [0.9,1]. Many processors will go into a "denormal" mode near zero. For a while, some Intel chips slowed down so dramatically to deal with denormals that "denormal spikes" appeared in signal processing apps (especially in LP filters) and people recommended AMD for audio processing. People actually added small amounts of noise near zero to code around the slowness.

Answer (score 5):

Cast them to **double** inside the function.

---

Where you're going to run into trouble is when the denominator is near zero, obviously. Your slope will approach infinity. So a lot depends on what you want to do with the slope. Sometimes, if you know your delta y is going to be near zero, you can calculate the reciprocal of slope and use that instead. You can even detect which is smaller--the absolute value of deltax or deltay and return the slope or 1/slope. Also look into atan2().

---

If you know the input is in decimal, and you want the output in decimal as well, you can overcome the loss of precision that is inherent in converting floats to binary and back by doing all calculations with a decimal library. I remember how pleased I was when I used Atari BASIC for decimal calculations, as it used the 6502's BCD mode.

Comment: Division by near-zero is okay; if the result were +INF or -INF that's okay too: I'd want to know if the slope is straight up and down.

Comment: My point is that it really depends on what you're going to do with the slope. If you perform a calculation with the slope, it might help to pull the slope calculation out of the function and put it inline into the equation that uses the slope. Then you can look at the equation as a whole for precision problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo.  You probably mean

```
return  dXa/(dYa - dYb) - dXb/(dYa - dYb);
```

I would say that the first form that you gave has higher precision.  If dXa and dXb are close and large, then you would lose precision in the two divisions before subtracting.

Comment: 'Close and large': I don't see how the 'large' part contributes to your argument.  If the dX's are close, the difference between them will be small regardless of the magnitude.  I mean, it's _floating_ point, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind burning some extra cycles you can get better accuracy by doing a loop.

Calculate slope of the line segment between A and B.

Calculate slope of the line segment between {(Xa - (Xa -Xb)), (Ya -(Ya -Yb)} and {(Xb + (Xa - Xb)), (Yb +(Ya - Yb))}... Basically A - slope and B + slope.

Then compare the resulting slopes. If the difference is too high (choose the threshold you want) then keep going, and average all of the slopes at the end.

This can help smooth out anomalies caused by floating point arithmetic for very small slopes.

Comment: Intriguing, and whether I end up doing this it's not really the 'answer' I was looking for.  This is more an algorithmic solution than a simple 'rejigging'

Comment: Well, you asked "I'd like to know if there is a way to improve the accuracy of calculating a slope". Sadly, the answer is no beyond employing tricks and maybe casting to double as Nosredna suggests.